# Possible to Install ROS on Snow Leopard Using Xcode < 4?

Tags: macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to install ROS on OS X Snow Leopard with Xcode version 3.2.6? I realize the installation documentation says Xcode 4 is required, but I was hoping that since ROS predates OS X Lion & Xcode 4, it would be possible to install & use ROS somehow.

I would love to upgrade to Lion, but my Macbook Pro is evidently just a little too outdated to handle it, according to the App Store.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12652/possible-to-install-ros-on-snow-leopard-using-xcode-%3C-4?/) by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the Homebrew installation instructions here:

http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

I cannot guarantee that this will work, but I don't know of any specific reasons it wouldn't.

You will still need to have this line in your ~/.bashrc exactly from the instructions:

```
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=osxbrew:lion
```

This will fool rosdep into thinking you are running lion.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommytwoeyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1653/tommytwoeyes/) on 2012-02-18**:
Thanks! I will try that.